# Springboot Couchbase Application can not be deployed in windows

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase

I am developing a Springboot application which connects to a remote Couchbase server to fetch data. The application is working fine for the local Couchbase server in my machine. But when I configured the API properties for the remote database, it throws a java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException. Following given is my error log.

```
2020-08-31 08:50:50.596  WARN 12692 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fileUploadController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'predictionService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'predictionServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'predictionDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'predictionDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'predictionRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'couchbaseRepositoryOperationsMapping' defined in class path resource [com/example/couchbaseService/Configuration/CouchbaseConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'repositoryOperationsMapping' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'couchbaseTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/example/couchbaseService/Configuration/CouchbaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate]: Factory method 'couchbaseTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'couchbaseBucket' defined in class path resource [com/example/couchbaseService/Configuration/CouchbaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket]: Factory method 'couchbaseClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
2020-08-31 08:50:50.642  INFO 12692 --- [           main] c.c.client.core.env.CoreEnvironment      : Shutdown kvIoPool: success
2020-08-31 08:50:50.645  INFO 12692 --- [           main] c.c.client.core.env.CoreEnvironment      : Shutdown viewIoPool: success
2020-08-31 08:50:50.652  INFO 12692 --- [           main] c.c.client.core.env.CoreEnvironment      : Shutdown queryIoPool: success
2020-08-31 08:50:50.656  INFO 12692 --- [           main] c.c.client.core.env.CoreEnvironment      : Shutdown searchIoPool: success
2020-08-31 08:50:50.659  INFO 12692 --- [           main] c.c.client.core.env.CoreEnvironment      : Shutdown Core Scheduler: success
2020-08-31 08:50:50.659  INFO 12692 --- [       Thread-5] c.c.client.core.env.CoreEnvironment      : Shutdown Netty: success
2020-08-31 08:50:50.662  INFO 12692 --- [           main] c.c.client.core.env.CoreEnvironment      : Shutdown Runtime Metrics Collector: success
2020-08-31 08:50:50.666  INFO 12692 --- [           main] c.c.client.core.env.CoreEnvironment      : Shutdown Latency Metrics Collector: success
2020-08-31 08:50:50.683  INFO 12692 --- [      cb-io-1-2] c.c.client.core.endpoint.Endpoint        : [][KeyValueEndpoint]: Got notified from Channel as inactive, attempting reconnect.
2020-08-31 08:50:50.690  INFO 12692 --- [entExecutor-2-2] c.c.client.core.env.CoreEnvironment      : Shutdown IoPool: success
2020-08-31 08:50:50.703  INFO 12692 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
```

As I couldn't figure out the cause, I tested the API in different windows machines and all attempts gave the same error. But, API successfully starts in a MacOS machine and works fine. I am using Java 11 and Couchbase enterprise edition 6.5.0. My springboot version is 2.0.1. Can anyone help me on this to figure out the cause? Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked your firewall or antivirus settings?

Comment: I disabled the firewall and tried again . But problem still exists.

Answer (score 2):

If you claim that it works on a Mac, and there's no problem with the code, then the problem could be with your corporate networking policy. Often times, companies have different profiles for Windows than Macs. It could also be a firewall/antivirus blocking outgoing traffic on your PC that Mac doesn't have.

To verify this theory, run a Couchbase server locally on your PC and see if you can connect to it.

Comment: Thanks! The API connects with the Couchbase server in my local machine. Problem happens when connecting to the remote one.

Comment: Sounds like you need IT support, not online advice.